# "selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES" works only at first selection of any Cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkcoordinateregion

**Introduction :**

I have done an app,Where the user can search particular place in a map. I have a mapView and a list view which contains UITableView in which i have displayed the name of the places(search results) parsed from the google API.

**My Problem:**

Here my problem is when i select a specific table cell, Corresponding to the name the place should be focused in the mapView With its annotation and the annotation SHOULD BE SELECTED automatically. Hence i made this code. Also i works when i make 1st select and also when i make a new search but from the second select it never works. (i.e)

1.The annotation works

2.The zooming works

3.BUT **from the second select** THE "**selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES**" DOES NOT WORKS. please some one help in fixing this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       [tableView reloadData];
       [mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];

        annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
        NSDictionary *searchResults1 = [LocationDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        annotation.title = [searchResults1  valueForKey:@"name"];
        annotation.subtitle=[searchResults1 valueForKey:@"formatted_address"];
        annotation.coordinate= CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[searchResults1 valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue], [[searchResults1 valueForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]);

        [mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
        [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];


     [mapView setRegion: MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotation.coordinate, 1000, 1000)  animated:YES];
     [tableView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the annotation before you select it?

Comment: ya i did :( but it dint help

Comment: How can you do a second select if the tableView is removed from the superview? It won't be on the screen anymore. Perhaps you are adding it again and it isn't connected up properly to the same mapview or line items

Comment: The tableView and mapView are the subView of the rootView so it works. Please have a look http://pastie.org/8447786

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in your searchBarSearchButtonClicked: as follows,

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBarr
{

for(annotation in mapView.annotations)
{
    [mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:NO];

}
searchData = searchBarr.text;
```

Your mistake was that you didn't set the animated value for `selectAnnotation:animated:` to `NO` . Hence it is showing the last annotation. Which is active.